# Go to a new html file depending on time of day

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to JavaScript so I wondered if any of you could solve this puzzle. This is obviously completely wrong but hopefully you see what I need.
I need the index.html to redirect to a new .html file depending on time of day.

```
function getIndex() {
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
if (0 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 5) {
document.write("night.html");
}
if (5 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 11) {
document.write("morning.html");
}
if (11 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 16) {
document.write("day.html");
}
if (16 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 22) {
document.write("evening.html");
}
if (22 <= currentTime&&currentTime <= 24) {
document.write("night.html");
}
}

getIndex();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to redirect page using `window.location.href`

```
function getIndex() {
  var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
  if (0 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 5) {
      window.location.href = 'night.html';
  } else if (5 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 11) {
      window.location.href = 'morning.html';
  } else if (11 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 16) {
     window.location.href = 'day.html';
  } else if (16 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 22) {
    window.location.href = 'evening.html';
  } else if (22 <= currentTime&&currentTime <= 24) {
    window.location.href = 'night.html';
  }
}

getIndex();
```

Rest all you code is fine

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way of going about things.

```
function getIndex() {
    var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getHours();

    var pages = ['night', 'morning', 'day', 'evening', 'night'];
    var eTimes = [0, 5, 11, 16, 22, 24];

    for (var i = 0; i < eTimes.length - 1; i++) {
        if (eTimes[i] <= h && h < eTimes[i + 1]) {
            window.location.href = pages[i] + '.html';
        }
    }
}

getIndex();
```